# How can I avoid EInvalidPointer error when using TObjectDictionary in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tdictionary

The program receives `product information datas` through window message.
Incoming datas processed in `TProductInstance.PutProductData` procedure.

Product information contains date, name, price.
I want to store datas as `TObjectDictionary`. The key is same date of the product and value is product information data list as TObjectList.
Also I want to maintain datas only in latest 7 days.
By the way, when I remove the item from TObjectDictionary for maintaining, error occurs like below.

> First chance exception at $75214598.
> Exception class EInvalidPointer with message 'Invalid pointer operation'. Process product.exe (3848).

This is caused by `FProductDictionary.Remove(StringKey);`.

How can I avoid `EInvalidPointer` error with maintain latest 7 days datas?

```
type
  TProductItem = class(TObject)
  private
    FDate: String;
    FName: String;
    FPrice: Integer;
    procedure SetDate(const value: String);
    procedure SetName(const value: String);
    procedure SetPrice(const value: Integer);
  public
    property Date: String read FDate write SetDate;
    property Name: String read FName write SetName;
    property Price: Integer read FPrice write SetPrice;
    constructor Create(const date, name: String; const price: Integer);
  end;

  TProductItemList = class(TObjectList<TProductItem>);

type
  TProductInstance = class(TObject)
  private
  public
    FLatestDate: String;

    FProductList: TProductItemList;
    FProductDictionary: TObjectDictionary<String, TProductItemList>;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure PutProductData(var Data: LP_Data);
  end;

implementation

constructor TProductInstance.Create;
begin
  FLatestDate := '';

  FProductList := TProductItemList.Create;
  FProductDictionary := TObjectDictionary<String, TProductItemList>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
end;

procedure TProductInstance.PutProductData(var Data: LP_Data);
var
  StringKey: String;
begin
  if (Trim(LP_Data^.date) <> FLatestDate) then
  begin
    FProductDictionary.AddOrSetValue(Trim(LP_Data^.date), FProductList);
    for StringKey in FProductDictionary.Keys do
    begin
      if (GetDateToInt(Trim(LP_Data^.date)) - GetDateToInt(FLatestDate) > 7) then
        FProductDictionary.Remove(StringKey);
    end;
    FProductList.Free;
  end;
  FProductList.Add(TProductItem.Create(Trim(LP_Data^.date), Trim(LP_Data^.name), Trim(LP_Data^.price)));
  FLatestDate := Trim(LP_Data^.date);
end;
```

**UPDATED**

```
type
  TProductItem = class(TObject)
  private
    FDate: String;
    FName: String;
    FPrice: Integer;
    procedure SetDate(const value: String);
    procedure SetName(const value: String);
    procedure SetPrice(const value: Integer);
  public
    property Date: String read FDate write SetDate;
    property Name: String read FName write SetName;
    property Price: Integer read FPrice write SetPrice;
    constructor Create(const date, name: String; const price: Integer);
  end;


type
  TProductInstance = class(TObject)
  private
  public
    FLatestDate: String;

    FProductList: TObjectList<TProductItem>;
    FProductDictionary: TObjectDictionary<String, TObjectList<TProductItem>>;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure PutProductData(var Data: LP_Data);
  end;

implementation

constructor TProductInstance.Create;
var
  LProductItem: TProductItem;
  LProductItemList: TObjectList<TProductItem>;
  LStringList: TStringList;
begin
  FLatestDate := '';

  FProductList := TObjectList<TProductItem>.Create;
  FProductDictionary := TObjectDictionary<String, TObjectList<TProductItem>>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
end;

procedure TProductInstance.PutProductData(var Data: LP_Data);
var
  StringKey: String;
begin
  FProductList.Add(TProductItem.Create(Trim(LP_Data^.date), Trim(LP_Data^.name), Trim(LP_Data^.price)));  
  if (Trim(LP_Data^.date) <> FLatestDate) then
  begin
    LProductItemList := TObjectList<ProductItem>.Create;
    for LProductItem in FProductList do
    begin
      LProductItemList.Add(LProductItem);
    end;

    FProductDictionary.AddOrSetValue(Trim(LP_Data^.date), LProductItemList);
    FProductList.Clear;

    LStringList := TStringList.Create;
    for StringKey in FProductDictionary.Keys do
    begin
      if (GetDateToInt(Trim(LP_Data^.date)) - GetDateToInt(FLatestDate) > 7) then
      begin
        LStringList.Add(StringKey);
      end;
    end;
    for StringKey in LStringList do
    begin
      FProductDictionary.Remove(StringKey);
    end;

    FreeAndNil(LStringList);
  end;
end;
```

Updated code occurs `EInvalidPointer` error on `FProductDictionary.Remove(StringKey);` What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you present is incomplete. You did not show the destructor for `TProductInstance`. For a question such as this you should always supply a simple MCVE. This is quite easy to achieve in a single console .dpr file.

Looking at what we can see, it is clear that the lifetime management in the code is broken. Let us critique this method.

```
procedure TProductInstance.PutProductData(var Data: LP_Data);
var
  StringKey: String;
begin
  if (Trim(LP_Data^.date) <> FLatestDate) then
  begin
    FProductDictionary.AddOrSetValue(Trim(LP_Data^.date), FProductList);
    for StringKey in FProductDictionary.Keys do
    begin
      if (GetDateToInt(Trim(LP_Data^.date)) - GetDateToInt(FLatestDate) > 7) then
        FProductDictionary.Remove(StringKey);
    end;
    FProductList.Free;
  end;
  FProductList.Add(TProductItem.Create(Trim(LP_Data^.date), Trim(LP_Data^.name), 
    Trim(LP_Data^.price)));
  FLatestDate := Trim(LP_Data^.date);
end;
```

Because `FProductDictionary` owns its values, when you do

```
FProductDictionary.AddOrSetValue(Trim(LP_Data^.date), FProductList);
```

then `FProductDictionary` becomes the owner of `FProductList`. That means that you should not destroy `FProductList` ever. However, you do exactly that:

```
FProductList.Free;
```

So you are going to be destroying `FProductList` multiple times which is a clear error.

What to do next? You need to deal with the lifetime issues. I cannot know from the code presented here what you are trying to achieve, and how the lifetime should be managed. You will need to work out who is responsible for owning what, and make sure that you stick to a clear lifetime management policy.

On the face of it, my best guess would be that you need to remove the `FProductList` field. When you need to add a new item to `FProductDictionary`, instantiate a new instance of `TProductItemList`, populate it, and add it to the dictionary. At that point the dictionary takes control of the lifetime of the `TProductItemList`.

As one final comment, I would suggest that the type `TProductItemList` is pointless. I would remove it. Use `TObjectList<TProductItem>` to make the code clearer to the reader. The reader can look at `TObjectList<TProductItem>` and know immediately what it is, since `TObjectList<T>` is such a ubiquitous type.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add new instance of TProductItemList to FProductDictionary. But FProductList was made as global variable for stack up product information datas. Because product datas incoming every 1 second. How can I stack up datas for adding data list to FProductDIctionary?

Comment: Stack up the data somewhere. When you are ready to add it, create a new product list, transfer the stacked data there, add to dictionary, and then clear the stacked data ready for more to arrive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. I will try. And then I will reply here again.

Comment: @MartynA I think `Dictionary` is more proper in my case.

Comment: @MartynA means to use a queue to stack up the incoming data. I don't think I can really write the rest of your code for you. I've shown you where your runtime error comes from, which is what you asked.

Comment: It's just the same problem, but a level down. Now `FProductList` owns the items. But you add them into `LProductItemList` and now both `FProductList` and `LProductItemList` own each item. You have to have exactly one owner. You can use `Extract` to remove an item from an object list, without destroying it. You could do that for each item rather than calling `FProductList.Clear`. Or you could set `FProductList.OwnsItems` to be `False`. Either for all time, or just before you call `Clear` on it.

Comment: Anyway, I hope you don't make any more edits to the question. I think I've now answered two distinct questions. Please don't expect us to debug your entire program. We help you fix one bug, but then your want us to fix all the new bugs that you introduced!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much. I have changed `FProductList.OwnsObject` to `False`. And it works well. Actually, I didn't know about `OwnsObject` property means. But I know that means now.